# bootstrapselect close button is large in size

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-select

I need to solve the bootstrap select search and close button in view.I have uploaded image in below link

[bootstrap select dropdown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhXMM.png)

**javascript**

```
$('#class_list_for_fee_report').multiselect({

        enableClickableOptGroups: true,
        enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        maxHeight: 350,

    });
```

**html**

```
<select class ="col-lg-3 col-xs-3" multiple="multiple" id="class_list_for_fee_report" value="multiselect-all">
   <?php foreach ($batchList as $batch):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $batch->getId(); ?>" selected><?php echo $batch->getBatchName(); ?></option>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before i were used library is

by replacing these library gives me the solution

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap includes classes like

```
<button class="btn btn-lg">Done</button> // large
<button class="btn btn-sm">Done</button> // small
<button class="btn btn-xs">Done</button> // extra-small
```

These classes manipulate the size of the button, hope it is something you are looking for.

Comment: please click that image **bootstrap select dropdown image** . So you will get